# Android parse.com load relational objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is it possible to load objects that are related in one API call? For example, I have two Classes: Post and Comment. In Post class I have relation that is one to many to Comment I want to load all Post objects but with related Comment objects in one API call.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation on [Parse](http://parse.com). It depends if you are using an array or a relationship, but it is all documented under Queries/Relationships.